# I want to get windows login name instead of SQL login name

Tags: sql, vb.net

I use different username & password to connect SQL database & log in windows. I'm using trigger to track database insert, Update & Delete. For this purpose I use SUSER_NAME. Its show SQL login name. I want to get windows login name instead of SQL login name.

Comment: A short google will show you what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SUSER_NAME()` or `SUSER_SNAME()`

If neither of these are returning your AD account you logged in via, check you are using AD trusted connections and not SQL auth.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/suser-sname-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Thank Andrew. This will fire SQL user. I need Windows Log in user.

Comment: @Mark - edited, I'm suspicious you are not using AD Auth

Comment: Our Server Administrators didn't grant permission to all users. But only system operation users (hard code users) can enter to system. Login user name can pass from vb form to sql procedure as parameter. But I want to know without passing username as parameter I want to get Windows login user name & store through trigger

Comment: If they are logged in via a SQL Login, you can only access which AD account they are if it is passed by the application / or the application sets it on session context if the connection is private. You can't access their AD account name when logged in as a SQL Login that I am aware of.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Ok I can understand. There is no way to access windows login name from sql.

Comment: In your situation, directly - no, indirectly, yes. Either through session context being set or being passed by the application.